# Sharing code between multiple micro-services

Tags: java, spring, microservices

I am developing three micro-services

1. View offers
2. Add offers(for administrator)
3. Opt offers

View offers is used to show offers to customer and Add offer used by service admins to link offer to customer and if offer is linked to customer, view offer will return that offer in response. Opt offers is used by customer to avail the offer.

While designing, I realized that all 3 services share same functionality, but also have their own logic.

Should I use shared code while developing these API or each API must have its own code base?

Comment: There is no "must".  You may want to avoid replicating code though.

Comment: This is a very vaguely worded question. The questions one may ask what best practices are there. What is the technical skill of your team. Maintenance cost, Security, ect. There is plenty on Stackoverflow about modular applications.

Comment: The question is highly opinion based. Some may advise you to deploy a [shared-nothing architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared-nothing_architecture). Some will advise you to package common functionality in a shared library. Long story short: this is off-topic for SO due to the opinion-based nature of the question.

Comment: Generally, you start separately and once you have a clearer picture, you refactor. Part of refactoring is recognizing new objects and functions and pulling them out into separate packages. These separate packages can then be used in either microservice or any other project for that matter. It's unlikely that this kind of oversight can be designed from the start and you do not want to risk improperly tying dependencies together as then you're stuck. Make sure the packages/libraries/functions you extract are reusable and serve some purpose on their own.

Comment: IMO, all the 2 API's are part of same business functionality and should not be broken into differed micro-services.

Comment: I think this is quite clearly off-topic for SO, but from the little you've described here, IMHO it's overkill to make three separate microservices for these three functions - it sounds like a single 'offers' microservice which offers functions to add, view and opt would be far more appropriate. Think carefully about whether the additional complexity and overhead of splitting into microservices will be worth the perceived benefits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `maven` then you can use [Maven Modules](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html). This basically means you can extract the service code into separate module and include that module as a `pom` dependency in all 3 microservices.

[Here's](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/) an example of how to do it using `Spring`. If you are not using `Spring` then you can have a look at another example [here](http://www.codetab.org/tutorial/apache-maven/multi-module/multi-module-project/).